# RabbitMQ, Pika, and Twisted Reactor

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, twisted

I am having a problem with stopping my reactor while running a publisher to publish one message.  It seems like the reactor.stop() function executes before the message is actually sent and makes it on the queue.  Logically I think this makes sense, but it stops the code before the message makes it onto the queue.  When I take out the reactor.stop() the message makes it to the queue, but the reactor can't be stopped at all at this point.

```
@inlineCallbacks
def do_msg(connection):
    try:
        msg = content
        print "Connected to broker."

        chan = yield connection.channel()
        print "Channel constructed."

        # Declare exchange
        yield chan.exchange_declare(exchange="test_exchange", 
                  exchange_type="topic", durable=True)
        print "Exchange opened"

        # Declare queue
        yield chan.queue_declare(queue="test_queue", durable=True, 
                   exclusive=False)
        print "Queue opened."

        # Bind exchange and queue
        yield channel.queue_bind(exchange="test_exchange", 
                   queue="test_queue", routing_key="test_key")
        print "Exchange and Queue bound"

        print "Sending message: %s" % msg
        yield chan.basic_publish(exchange="test_exchange", body=msg, 
                 routing_key="test_key",                               
                 properties=BasicProperties(delivery_mode = 2))

    except Exception, e:
        print "ERROR: %s" % str(e)
    finally:
        yield connection.close()
        reactor.stop() # problem occurs here
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this? Is there a way to stop the reactor based on a condition that the message got to the broker?

Comment: From your code snippet, I do not see any indication of a binding being done between your queue and your exchange. Can you confirm this binding is in place?

Comment: That was my mistake when I put the code onto here.  I went ahead and edited the post to reflect it.  It does bind and works correctly.  I have played around with changing reactor.stop() to reactor.callLater(.0001, reactor.stop), and the message is sent and the reactor stops perfectly.  This solves the problem, but I do not know if this is reliable.

Comment: Just tried similar code and couldn't stop the reactor either. But it's a bit of an "odd" use case to publish to a queue and then stop the reactor. I say that because Twisted is generally intended for long running apps so I'm guessing the pika devs took that into consideration when developing their async adapters. I don't say this very often but is there any reason you need Twisted? Could you just run a synchronous script to publish to the queue? If all you all you need to do is publish 1 item and then stop, I'd use the synchronous syntax.

Comment: I appreciate the feedback.  I think that you are right that I can just use a synchronous script to publish.  I am focusing on using Twisted on the receiving end mostly.  The combination of both works the best I think.